# How to get auth user in Laravel controller when using the Laravel passport for API?

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

Will `auth::user()` work to get authorized credentials?

If not how can I get those?

Answer (score 2):

with passport i use `return Auth::guard('api')->user();`

Answer (score 0):

With Passport you can access the user via the request object:

```
$request->user()
```